# How do I avoid a media player crash when the back button is clicked on the device?

Tags: java, android

I have a media player in an Android Studio project. It crashes when the back button is clicked on the connected phone. This is what I gathered from the Logcat as the fault: "Unable to destroy activity {com.example.proj/com.example.proj.RadioActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.stop()' on a null object reference"

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stop();
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    stop();
}
```

I've found that if I click "Play" and then the back button, the app does not crash, suggesting that play is not a null object reference even if no media is playing).

How do I write a condition that if the back button is clicked and the MediaPlayer is not playing, do not destroy the player/app? I have no reference to the button in the code.

Comment: in ondestroy  check condition   `if(mediaPlayer!=null) {  stop();   }`

Comment: This was the solution @Redman. `@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mp!=null) {
            mp.stop();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be the solution if the problem was around onPause(). Worked in onDestroy.

Comment: @MarkLee I have updated my answer. If it is solution, set as corrected to close question. Happy coding :)

Comment: Clever @mac229.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in on back press :

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
        videoView.pause();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Override `onBackPressed()` in your activity and add your `stop()` method in it. Add the following code:

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed(){ 
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Overriding a super class method just to call it's super method is completely useless.

Comment: I mentioned to add a stop() method in it.